# Asp.Net MVC relatives paths for two application pointing to same code base

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a confusion that I am publishing my application on two server. The path for both is like:-
http://www.myapp.com/ and 
http://www.myapp2.com/myapp/

So for including any script, css or images, I have to given two path like:-

```
   <img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />  and
   <img src="~/myapp/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />
```

is there any way so that I do not need to put scripts twice.
I have tried:-

```
  <img src="./images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />
```

this works but how and why I am not sure.
Please explain or give any other suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Having relative paths `<img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />` is the right way, if you create virtual directories and map them to sites, then everything should work fine without any breaks in paths. And there is no need for you to load different paths for same content.

Comment: but ~ is not working for me but dot(.) is working

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution to the relative path problems in ASP.NET MVC applications is the use of T4MVC packages. T4MVC package is now becoming a standard to handle relative path and magic strings in MVC applications.

- Install T4MVC nuget in your MVC application

> Install-Package T4MVC

- Once installed, you will be able to see T4MVC.tt file in your solution.
- Right-click, and say "Run custom Tool"
- This should create constants for all static resources in your application.

Once done, you will be able to access the resources as follow:

```
<img src="@Links.Content.Images.ajax_loader_gif" alt="loading" />
```

And yes, you don't need to type-in, its just intelli-sense that will provide you resources to select.

One small thing, you may need to move your images to the "Content" folder in  your application, because as far as I am aware, T4MVC doesn't create constants for the folders (except, Content, Scripts, and Bundles). But yes, it is a standard to put Images in the Content folder.

Talking about the benefits -
- you don't need to worry about the deployment path. (Which is your original concern)
- also, this creates constants for all views, controllers and actions in your application (along with images, scripts, bundles, etc), and this way you can get rid of magic strings.

More about T4MVC - https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation